# Adding data to DOM, based on value of the key in handlebar

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I want to add data based on selected keys from my JSON to dom i.e i want data of only 100,101 to be added to the dom

**JSON**

```
var school = {
        "students": {
            "100": {
                "name": "abc",
                "bdate": "02/19/2000"

            },
            "101": {
                "name": "xyz",
                "sdate": "05/22/2001"

            },
            "103": {
                "name": "pqr",
                "sdate": "08/11/2001"

            }
        }

    };
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
       <ul>
       <script id="lst_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

          {{#each students}} 

    <li>

           {{name}}
           {{bdate}}            

    </li>

       {{/each}}


     </script>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Handlebar**

```
var studentsSelected = [100,101];
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#lst_template').html());
var container = $('.container ul');
```

How can i add data of only 100 and 101 to the handlebars ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that will do this for you so either you add a helper or you preprocess your data in JavaScript so that you can use a simple `{{#each}}`.

A helper would be pretty simple, something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_from', function(keys, obj, block) {
    var html = '';
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i)
        html += block.fn(obj[keys[i]]);
    return html;
});
```

and then template would be like this:

```
{{#each_from want_these students}}
    <li>{{name}} {{bdate}}</li>
{{/each_from}}
```

and call the template function like:

```
var html = tmpl({
    students:   school.students,
    want_these: ['100', '101']
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JkVWh/

If you want to pre-process your data then a simple loop is all you need:

```
var students = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < studentsSelected.length; ++i)
    students.push(school.students[studentsSelected[i]]);
```

and then a simple `{{#each students}}` in the template a `tmpl({ students: students })` call to get your HTML.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YQGRs/

---

Note that your `school` data has `bdate` in some and `sdate` in others, I don't know if this is intentional or not so I've left it alone.

And don't put your `<script id="lst_template">` inside the `<ul>`, you'll probably overwrite it while manipulating `<ul>`, you'll have a better time of things if you put it outside the `<ul>`.